# Optimizing cfdirectory command

Tags: coldfusion

I'm looking at a file that uses cfdirectory to check for the existence of a file.

```
<cfdirectory name="CheckForOrder" directory="\\server05\d$\Orders\" filter="#orderNumber#.pdf" 
                            listinfo="name" type="file">
```

The thing is, the cfdirectory command is super slow. I added `ListInfo = "name"` and that made a big difference, but it seems like there should be a better way to do this, since I already know the name of the file I want, I'm only checking as to whether or not it exists.

I did try `<cfset Exists = FileExists("\\server05\d$\Orders\#orderNumber#.pdf") >` But it returns false no matter what, I don't know if maybe that command doesn't work for networked drives?

Comment: have you tried <cfif FileExists(FileLocation)>?

Comment: I realized there was a type in my FileExists command, this did make a huge performance difference.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ColdFusion` `FileExists()` function to check the existence of a file at a specified location. Like this:

```
<cfif FileExists("\\server05\d$\Orders\#orderNumber#.pdf") >
     <!--- stuff you want to do in case the file exists--->
</cfif>
```

Read this for reference - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c66.html

Comment: Seems like @luke added the comment while I was posting my answer.